# vue3 composition api vuevalidate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-validator

I am using vue 3 and vueValidate to validate my form. https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/composition-api/api-review
Here is my simple form.
If the the input filed is empty, it should show error and if the input field is not empty it should show success. But currently it shows error even if the form is submitted after filling it.
I am not sure why it is showing error in both cases. Can you please tell me how to display vlidation error message.

```
  <form @submit="submitForm">
    <input 
      v-model="name"  type="text" 
      />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

js

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useVuelidate } from '@vuelidate/core'
import { required } from "@vuelidate/validators"

const formData = ref({
  name:''
})
const rules = {
  name: { required }
}
const v$ = useVuelidate(rules,formData);
console.log(v$);

const submitForm = async () => {
  const result = await v$.value.$validate();
  if(result) {
    alert('success')
  }else{
  alert('error')
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: formData is not used anywhere in the template

Comment: Hi @EstusFlask I have set const formDate = ref({name:''}), can you give me more hint? Thanks

Comment: currently it alerts me error message even if the form is filled

Comment: Here `v-model="name"` you bind to non-existent property and don't use formData

Comment: Thanks for your help v-model="formData.name" worked